# Onsen items list at the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, css, list, toolbar, onsen-ui

I am using `Onsen` framework for developing a mobile app. I'm trying to add a bottom menu but it doesn't work. I tried to use code that i get from [here](https://onsen.io/reference/ons-bottom-toolbar.html) and [here](https://onsen.io/reference/ons-list.html):

```
  <ons-bottom-toolbar class="bottom-toolbar">
    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
        ciao
      </ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
        ciao
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-bottom-toolbar>
```

But the result is weird:

[image]

Do you know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The bottom toolbar wasn't meant for having a whole list of items rather just one line things. It's meant to always be visible so it's expected to not be very big.

If you just want to have the items on the bottom it's going to be easier with a little css.

```
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/BKVVgb?editors=1100)